# How do you comment out a line in a reporting services function?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Nothing I have tried so far has worked...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To comment out source code that is placed within the code section of the Page Properties of a Reporting Services .rdl file simply place an apostrophe in front like so.

```
'ADD YOUR CODE HERE
```

Take a look at the following article on SQL Server Central:

[Adding Custom Code to Reporting Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/2803/)

You can also use an apostrophe to place comments in an Expression withing Reporting Services controls. This only appears to work if the comments come after the expression defintion. For example:

```
= "Test"
'Add Your comments here
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "reporting services function"? An MDX query? That would be "//".

Example:

```
//Comment
```

For report expressions, it's "'".

Example:

```
'Comment
```

Comment: Oh, okay. That should be ' then.

Answer (score -1):

use a single quote to open and close the comment..

`'example this will be ignored when the report is ran'`